# The term 'mkvirtualenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,or operable program

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

Below step by step answer:

To install virtual environment using use below pip command:

***`py -m pip install --user virtualenv`***

Then create new environment:

***`py -m venv projectName`***

Then you have to activate your virtual environment:

***`.\projectName\Scripts\activate`***

Once done with activating virtual environment, You’ll see “(myproject)” next to the command prompt.

Answer (score -2):

To install virtual environment using use below pip command:

***`py -m pip install --user virtualenv`***

Then create new environment:

**`py -m venv projectName`**

Then you have to activate your virtual environment:

**`.\projectName\Scripts\activate`**

Once done with activating virtual environment, You’ll see “(myproject)” next to the command prompt.